# How to update Item Property from list?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a generic list named mysoldier whose items has properties like height, weight etc. 
So after adding the soldiers (mysoldier.Add), I want to change the height of soldier. For that I used this:

```
 public void Increase Height() 
 { 
  for (int i = 0; i < mysoldier .Count; i++)
  { 
   if (this.mysoldier [i].height > 7) 
   { 
     this.mysoldier [i].height= 7; 
   } 
   else 
   {
    this.mysoldier [i].height+= 1; 
   } 
  }
```

but this is not changing height of only one specific object instead it changes height of all soldiers added to the container.

```
  public void IncreaseHeight(int i) //#, or mysoldier.Count - 1 (I believe) for last
  {
    if (this.mysoldier [i].height > 7) 
    { this.mysoldier [i].height= 7; } 
    else { this.mysoldier [i].height+= 1; }
  }
```

But with this code I change only the height of the soldier which is previously created. So please anyone  can point me what is wrong in the code?

Comment: the last piece of code is all right. you just have to modify the code from which you call `IncreaseHeight` to specify the correct index

Comment: `mysoldier` must be `mySoldier`.  (indeed as fernando explains, "mySoldiers" with an "s")

Comment: you should completely remove the "this." from the code.  As a general rule, never ever use "this." in Unity.  You sometimes see it in example code, and it's completely wrong.  So delete that.

Comment: note that if "height" is a float, you need to say 7f not 7, 1f not 1 and so on.

Comment: @JoeBlow Your "never use 'this' in Unity" makes no sense. Sometimes when the parameter and the class field have same names, you must use 'this' to refer the class field. Just don't use it for simpleness.

Comment: And you don't need to add `f` after the float constants, as the compiler will optimize it.

Comment: hi darkblade!  never use "this" in Unity.  it is inconceivable the OP will ever need to do so.  because in the Unity tag, there is an incredible number of absolute-beginner questions, it's important to focus on giving the simplest clearest answers possible.  you do need to "add the f", feel free to try it.  (note that it has no connection at all to "optimizing")

Comment: I disagree. He is a beginer, not a child. So you have to let him know that.

Comment: Hey guys can anyone point me towards  my mistek ?

Answer (score 0):

Some tips:

If it's a list, don't call it "mySoldier", call it "mySoldiers". This can make you confuse.
How are you creating these soldiers? Because... if you are creating then adding the same through a loop, you are adding the reference(memory address) to the list.
If you change something in one, you change in all of them.
If you just want to change the property for one specific item, just pass the index as a parameter to your function instead of using a for statement.

If you still have the problem going on, Let's try to solve it.

Comment: First I Create a public class Soldier add add all its properties like height, weight etc.. then a class constructor and create List of soldiers and add soldiers to new new list mysoldiers with button